# Why is the variable "hd" unbound here?

Tags: ocaml

```
let f x = 
  match x with 
    ((2, 4)::xr)             -> 42
  | [(1, y); (_, 3); (_, 4)] -> 5  
  | [(x, _); (u, w)]         -> u + x 
  | [(44, 11); (12, 3)]      -> 42
  | (x::xr)                  -> fst (hd xr)
```

I've tried running `f[(2, 4)]` for example.

ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on what `f` is supposed to be doing with it's argument.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't described the environment you're running in, so it's not really possible to say for sure. But `hd` is defined in the `List` module. Most likely you need to write `List.hd` instead of `hd`:

```
# hd;;
Error: Unbound value hd
# List.hd;;
- : 'a list -> 'a = <fun>
#
```

Answer (score 2):

Jeffrey's answer seems likely. It's worth noting that you can accomplish this without ever calling `List.hd` by using pattern-matching to bind `x` to the first element of the head of the tail of the list. The head of the tail otherwise being "the second element in a list which has *at least* two elements."

```
let f x = 
  match x with 
    (2, 4)::xr               -> 42
  | [(1, y); (_, 3); (_, 4)] -> 5  
  | [(x, _); (u, w)]         -> u + x 
  | [(44, 11); (12, 3)]      -> 42
  | _::(x, _)::_             -> x
```

Assuming `hd` was meant to be `List.hd` in your original code, you may have gotten an exception. Of your previous patterns, only `(2, 4)::xr` can match a list with one element, and only if that element is `(2, 4)`.

As it is, the code I've shown now features non-exhaustive pattern-matching, and *that* could generate an exception.